# Android View Rotation skip elements

Tags: android, canvas

I have android application where I draw inside a view dynamically terrain and some pieces in order to rotate these pieces inside the view I use View.serRotation(deegre here), but this rotate the whole view terrain + pieces I want to rotate the pieces only without the terrain.
How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use two Views, one for terrain and another for pieces

Comment: How to overlap them ?

Comment: Wrap both views in a RelativeLayout and for both set `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`